# get youtube/dailymotion/vimeo/metacafe/break etc downloadable link ios

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, youtube

How to get a downloadable link from video sites like dailymotion/youtube in ios? I was trying to get that link from javascript by calling "stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString" but I dont know how to use that because I am not good at javascript.
For now I am using a UIWebView for displaying the webpage but I dont know how to fetch downloadable link. I googled it but found nothing. I hope someone here might guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *getURL = @"";
getURL = [self.mainWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"function getURL() {
        return document.getElementsByTagName('VIDEO')[0].src;
    } getURL();"];

if ([getURL length] == 0) {
    getURL = [self.mainWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"function getURL() {
        return document.getElementsByTagName('Video')[0].src;
    } getURL();"];
}
if ([getURL length] == 0) {
    getURL = [self.mainWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"function getURL() {
        return document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].src;
    } getURL();"];
}
```

Comment: It's only works for YouTube Videos playing in UIWebView fro me till now :(